# Dockerfile Copy not working for Nextcloud container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, copy, nextcloud

I'm trying to deploy a Nextcloud container, where the config is copied from the local directory to the container. I'm not getting any error when building or running the container, and I can see the steps are successfully executed per the terminal. Regardless, the copied file simply is not in the container. What's going on here?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nextcloud:latest

# Copy local config
COPY ./config.php /var/www/html/config
```

All the evidence:
[image: Local file COPY not working]

Thanks!

Comment: Could you run 'ls' in yours local directory with dockerfile?

Comment: @matchish That is in the first row of my screenshot. There are 2 files contained: Dockerfile and config.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is copied but is being deleted later.

This is a very typical scenario, and in this cases, the best you can do is to see what happens in the parent image `nextcloud:latest` once the container starts.

In [nextcloud's Dockerfile](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/63438ef792fdedd4ceb80664d22391aca21f6bd1/18.0/apache/Dockerfile#L150) you can see

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

if we open [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/63438ef792fdedd4ceb80664d22391aca21f6bd1/18.0/apache/entrypoint.sh#L100) in the line 100 you can see clearly that the content of `/var/www/html/config` is modified

You can maybe do any of these options

- Copy the file to a different temporary location, and create your own `entrypoint` (you can copy-paste from the original one to hit the ground running, or you can try to figure out a fancier solution)
- Or also you can copy the file after creating and running the container

  ```
  docker cp config.php copytest:/var/www/html/config
  ```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Actually I'm using docker-compose (omitted from my OP). Then would you just add the file as a mounted volume?

Comment: Since entrypoint.sh is doing a RSYNC still it could be deleted, but apparently nextcloud recommends exactly using volumes, so yes you can give it a try.

take a look at this one
https://github.com/nextcloud/docker#persistent-data

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to use a volume mounting solution, and still running into (similar?) errors... I opened a new post about this here, in case you're familiar with Nextcloud issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159869/cannot-mount-config-directory-in-nextcloud-docker-container